# OAuth2 grant_type missing

Tags: google-oauth

I am getting error that required parameter `grant_type` is missing in the request.

Using OAuth2 for Webserver application.

Please see below the code:

```
var httpClient : HTTPClient = new HTTPClient();
httpClient.setTimeout(3500);
httpClient.setRequestHeader("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpClient.open("POST", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");    

var param1:String = "code="+Encoding.toURI(pdict.CurrentHttpParameterMap.code.value.split('.')[0]);
var param2:String = "client_id="+pdict.session.custom.client_id;
var param3:String = "client_secret="+pdict.session.custom.client_secret;
var param4:String = "redirect_uri="+Encoding.toURI(pdict.session.custom.redirect_uri);
var param5:String = "scope=";
var param6:String = "grant_type=authorization_code";
```

Comment: Please show the complete code of this token request.

Comment: There is only one line which I didn't write above i.e. httpClient.send(param1 + "&" + param2 + "&" + param3 + "&" + param4 + "&" + param5 +  "&" + param6);

Comment: Then you are missing something "grant_type=authorization_code" is step two in authentication.  You need to request access first.  What language are you doing this in? is that Java?  Which API do you want to access?

Comment: It is DemandwareScript. I am able to resolve the issue when I used below syntax - var client_secret : HTTPRequestPart = new HTTPRequestPart("client_secret", pdict.session.custom.client_secret);

Answer (score 0):

Using below syntax i.e. passing variables as part of Request body solved it.

var client_secret : HTTPRequestPart = new HTTPRequestPart("client_secret", pdict.session.custom.client_secret);